# How to avoid having to Power Reset my laptop each time I use it

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, static-discharge

Each time I use it, I cannot power on my Acer E5 unless I do a "Power Reset" first. If I remove the battery and A/C adapter then hold down the power button for 30 seconds, my laptop will turn on.  When I turn it off, I can turn it back on within 15 minutes with no problem.  After 15 minutes, I must do a power reset again. I recently replaced the battery and it charges and holds a charge properly.  The power LED does not light up when the A/C is connected except after I do the power reset.  Then it works fine until I turn off the laptop.  I have read posts that suggest that this is caused by static electricity build up but I don't know how to prevent it. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: replace the system board

Comment: It could be a motherboard problem, it could be a battery problem (you already replaced the battery).  Did the problem happen before you replaced the battery?

Comment: Well, I am still plagued with this problem.  I did not have this problem before I replaced the battery.  The first battery that I purchased was defective ( I noticed that it was actually broken).  I purchased a second battery which seems to work fine but I still have the problem.  Is there a component in the laptop that I am missing?  I have checked the battery, power adapter and the power switch. Before a power reset noting works,  fan, drive, LED indicators, but after a reset all works normally. Is there a way to test the power section of the motherboard?  Is there a way to repair the MB?

Comment: More......After the power reset the laptop operates on A/C only or battery only the LED's work normally and the battery charges and discharges normally.  But after turning off the laptop for more than 15 minutes it won't come on without a power reset.  Turned off for less than about 15 minutes it powers up fine.  It retains the correct date and time so I presume that the BIOS battery is working.

Comment: I received a suggestion from a member who told me to try turning off fast boot.  I turned it off along with sleep and hibernate and PROBLEM SOLVED!  Thanks, to the Tech Support community.